# Normalizing target coordinates

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, computer-vision, normalization

Im trying to train the multi output model. Im loading the images in batches as follows,

```
def get_batch_features(self, idx):
    return np.array([load_image(im) for im in self.im_list[idx * self.bsz: (1 + idx) * self.bsz]])
```

Following is my load_image function where im normalizing the images to range between 0 and 255 as follows

```
def load_image(im):
    return img_to_array(load_img(im, target_size=(224, 224))) / 255.
```

Im loading the labels which are the target coordinates of 4 xy coordinates.

```
def get_batch_labels(self, idx):
    return self.labels[idx * self.bsz: (idx + 1) * self.bsz,:]
```

How do I normalize the target coordinates by scaling it to  [-1, 1]? since im not scaling it, im getting a huge validation loss as the model is overfitting. Is there by any means that i can scale the target coordinates  between [-1,1]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your target coordinates are somewhere in the interval `[0,223]` as this is how many pixels your images have, what about just adjusting this to `[-111.5,111.5]` by subtracting `111.5` and dividing by `111.5` afterwards?

```
return (self.labels[idx * self.bsz: (idx + 1) * self.bsz,:]-111.5)/111.5
```

Actually, from my experience, you don't need to hit `[-1,1]` precisely, it should be sufficient to just divide them by `100` so that they are in the right order of magnitude. Besides that, you could also compute the statistics over all labels and normalize them so that they follow zero mean/unit variance which is a common strategy.

Comment: oh my goodness... you are my savior...  my val loss was previously in four digits... it was 3367... after normalizing in this way, its only 0.04... thank you so much. after training is over, i will update you how it turned out to be

Comment: i tried predicting. The output is an array of elements of negative dimension as well. May I know why?

Comment: @Roger Well, you will have to reverse the normalisation again, for example `prediction*111.5+111.5`